# IIS7 Basic Authentication on PHP Site

Tags: php, iis-7, basic-authentication, subdirectory

I have a PHP5 site running on IIS7 and I just wanted to add basic authentication on a subfolder called admin.

I enabled both anonymous authentication and basic authentication and I just want to turn off anonymous authentication on the subfolder in order to force the basic authentication?

Any suggestions?

I tried adding a web.config in the subfolder with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <authentication>
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
      </authentication>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is authorization, not authentication. You can leave anonymousAuthentication enabled, but just don't authorize users who haven't logged in. Use the non managed Url Authentication module ([link text](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/142/understanding-iis-70-url-authorization/)), and setup your subfolder's web.config file like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authorization>
                <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
                <add accessType="Deny" users="?" />
            </authorization>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Rather than hand editing the config file, you can also the "Authorization Rules" feature in the IIS admin.

Answer (score 0):

If you want folder authentications, look to your applicationHost.config file and use something to this effect:

```
    <location path="Default Web Site/css">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
                <basicAuthentication enabled="true" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```